# How to detect if browser is compatible with ES2015

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a big chunk of JS libraries that I should rewrite since it's really old and outdated. So, I decided to come up with a solution where I would just use most of *ES2015* features like [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters).

The thing is, I am sure all the clients would not have their browser up-to-date and I am confused whether I will face any issue regarding their browser is compatible with my new JS libs.

So, I was wondering if I could detect whether the client browsers are compatible with ES2015. And if not, I would just include my old JS library.

I am looking for a solution like [Conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html), but I am getting nowhere to solution.

Any help in HTML, JS or PHP is appreciated. Please kindly suggest your advice.

Comment: For now there's simply no browser compatible with the *whole* ES2015. See https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

Comment: Good question. For starters, I think this would best be applied as a dependency manager configuration so that this would load an alternate version of a script. As for detection, I wonder if the easiest method would be something like `eval("function(a,b,...args) { }");`, and checking for a syntax error. A reminder, of course, that "eval is evil", but if you keep in mind to only use it for an exact inline string it might be a little safer.

Comment: A lot of ES6 features can't be simply polyfilled because it is new Syntax, so you would need to have two versions of all your code; an ES6 version and a Legacy version (perhaps compiled from the ES6 version using Babel?). Feature detection would have to be done in `try..catch` because if it isn't supported it **will** throw errors. You could instead bring the code up to ES5 with shims instead though, which would mean you have a single code base.

Answer (score 6):

> I was wondering if I could detect whether the client browsers are
>   compatible with ES2015. And if not, I would just include my old JS
>   library.

You cannot do that, simply because AFAIK there's no browser that fully supports ES2015. Also, you don't really want to maintain two different versions of your code, because it's painful and it could get messy really quick.

The approach nowadays is to use a *transpiler*, which is sort of a compiler that compiles your ES2015 code to ES5 (the JavaScript that every browser knows). It is still kind of messy, but at least you get to write only one version of your code, and it's ES2015.

I think [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) (formerly 6to5) is the most popular transpiler. You can check out their website for getting started.

---

As to answer your actual question,

> How to detect if browser is compatible with ES2015

You can do that in many ways. I'm not sure what could be the most reliable one, but for example you could simply try on your browser's console:

```
'Promise' in window
```

If this statement returns `true`, then the current browser supports promises, which is a new feature of ES2015, so you could assume that it supports most of the features of ES2015.

This is not enough for most cases though; you may want to be 100% sure that what you're using is not going to throw a `SyntaxError` in any old browser.

A solution could be to manually check for each feature you want to use. For example, if you need the Fetch API, you could create a function that tells you if the current browser supports it:

```
function isFetchAPISupported() {
    return 'fetch' in window;
}
```

You can do this for any new API you need. However, if you need something *syntactically* different, I think your only bet is `eval()` (as Katana314 suggested). For example, in order to check support for rest parameters you could do:

```
function isRestSupported() {
    try {
        eval('function foo(bar, ...rest) { return 1; };');
    } catch (error) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

This works great in Firefox, because the rest parameters are supported.
It works as well on Safari, returning `false` because rest parameters are *not* supported there yet.

Comment: *If this statement returns true, then the browser is "compatible" with ES2015.* That's just wrong. It means only that the browser provides native promises.

Comment: What would you do if `isRestSupported` returned `true` though? Using rest syntax in an unsupported browser is going to throw a syntax error when *parsed* rather than executed more than likely

Comment: @RGraham In my comment, I mentioned a dependency manager would have to configure for it. Eg, `partOfApp.js` and `partOfApp_ES5.js`. The latter could simply be a warning saying "Get a newer browser, hick!" if it's not a common-access site.

Comment: @Katana314 So you would need one file for each additional feature if for example the browser supported rest but not param defaults and each permutation of? Easier just to use Babel on existing codebase

Comment: @RGraham Well, I can't speak to the OP's reasons for not using a transpiler of some sort; they obviously have *some* plan they're thinking of.

Comment: @torazaburo thanks for the input. That sentence was wrong indeed; I rephrased my answer.

Comment: `if you need something syntactically different..` what do you mean? what's wrong with the first example (without the eval)? I don't understand

Comment: @vsync I mean "an ES2015 feature that has a syntax that is incompatible with older versions", such as the "fat arrows". How would you write a function that checks for the presence of such feature? The only thing that comes to my mind in this case is `eval`.